# How to use map/reduce to merge documents with some different element with newest status

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I have some documents like following data element, like doc.userid in doc.event1 but doc.userid is not existed in doc.event2, as following

```
doc.event1: userid='6908503',  probNumber='USP06HVU8NF', userTypeCode='M',status='OPEN',...
doc.event1: userid='6908503',  probNumber='USP02BUEIFR', userTypeCode='M',status='OPEN',...
doc.event1: userid='ABCCCCCC',  probNumber='GBP02M8RFKI', userTypeCode='M',status='OPEN',...
doc.event2: probNumber='USP06HVU8NF', status='CLOSE'.....
```

......

I need use doc.userid with doc.probNumber combination as the key in the map to get the latest status ones with given same probNumber, here is what I use in map and its results

```
function(doc) {
    if(doc.event){
       var idv = null;
             for (var idu in doc.users){
               if (doc.users[idu].userTypeCode == "M"){

                   idv = doc.users[idu].userId;
        }
            }
      emit([idv,doc.problemNumber],[doc.status]);
  }
}
```

results:

```
       key                   values
[null, "USP06HVU8NF"],     ["CLOSE"]
["6908503", "USP02BUEIFR"],["OPEN"]
["6908503", "USP06HVU8NF"],["OPEN"]
["ABCCCCCC", "GBP02M8RFKI"],["OPEN"]
```

How can I use reduce to merge result of [null, "USP06HVU8NF"] ["6908503", "USP06HVU8NF"] with latest status CLOSE as ["6908503", "USP06HVU8NF"],["CLOSE"] as expected?

```
["6908503", "USP06HVU8NF"],["CLOSE"]
["6908503", "USP02BUEIFR"],["OPEN"]
["ABCCCCCC", "GBP02M8RFKI"],["OPEN"]
```